# Increasing values of entries across several dictionaries using user input

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a part of a program that takes a users input, searches across several dictionaries to find a matching key, and then increase the corresponding entries value by 25.

```py
Strength = {"Acrobatics":5, "Crafting":5, "Axe":5, "Blunt Weapon":5, "Long Blade":5}
Intelligence = {"Alchemy":5, "Conjuration":5, "Enchant":5, "Thievery":5}
Willpower = {"Alteration":5, "Destruction":5, "Mysticism":5, "Restoration":5}
Agility = {"Block":5, "Light Armor":5, "Marksman":5, "Sneak":5}
Speed = {"Athletics":5, "Hand to Hand":5, "Short Blade":5, "Unarmored":5}
Endurance = {"Heavy Armor":5, "Medium Armor":5, "Spear":5}
Personality = {"Illusion":5, "Mercantile":5, "Speechcraft":5}
# Skill dictionaries, will be printed to a seperate file after all things are done

skilldict = {"Strength":Strength, "Intelligence":Intelligence, "Willpower":Willpower, "Agility":Agility, "Speed":Speed, "Endurance":Endurance, "Personality":Personality}

for alphakey, alphaentry in skilldict.items():
  if alphakey == usfavstat[0]:
      for key, entry in alphaentry.items(): 
            alphaentry[key] = entry + 5

for alphakey, alphaentry in skilldict.items():
  # Grabs a key, entry combination from skilldict, named differently to not cause error down the line
  if alphakey == usfavstat[1]:
    # If the key is equal to the second favored stat, continue
      for key, entry in alphaentry.items(): 
        # This works?
        # Nested for-loop grabbing a key, entry combination from a nested dict
            alphaentry[key] = entry + 5
            # Increases all values of entries by 5

mtemp = input("Enter major skills, seperated by a comma : ").title()
mtemp2 = mtemp.replace(" ", "")
majorskills = mtemp2.split(",")
# Stuff to increase corresponding skills by 25
```

I am unsure how to go about this. An example input would be "Acrobatics, Short Blade, Block, Speechcraft, Alteration". The desired output would have these skills at 30 in their respective dictionaries.

The for-loops with nested for-loops are irrelevant for this situation. I've included them to see if anyone would have a better means of achieving their goal, that being increasing all skills of an area by 5, based on user input in `usfavstat`, but this is secondary.

If there is information that would be beneficial to have, do comment and I'll add it if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Strength = {"Acrobatics":5, "Crafting":5, "Axe":5, "Blunt Weapon":5, "Long Blade":5}
Intelligence = {"Alchemy":5, "Conjuration":5, "Enchant":5, "Thievery":5}
Willpower = {"Alteration":5, "Destruction":5, "Mysticism":5, "Restoration":5}
Agility = {"Block":5, "Light Armor":5, "Marksman":5, "Sneak":5}
Speed = {"Athletics":5, "Hand to Hand":5, "Short Blade":5, "Unarmored":5}
Endurance = {"Heavy Armor":5, "Medium Armor":5, "Spear":5}
Personality = {"Illusion":5, "Mercantile":5, "Speechcraft":5}

skill_dict = {"Strength":Strength, "Intelligence":Intelligence, "Willpower":Willpower, "Agility":Agility, "Speed":Speed, "Endurance":Endurance, "Personality":Personality}

user_input = input("Enter major skills, seperated by a comma: ").title()
major_skills = [skill.strip() for skill in user_input.split(",")]

for skill in skill_dict:
  for major_skill in major_skills:
    if skill_dict.get(skill).get(major_skill):
      skill_dict[skill][major_skill] += 25

print(skill_dict)
```

I've re-named the variables a bit for my own convenience, but hope you get the idea.

By the way, I think `mtemp2 = mtemp.replace(" ", "")` is not a good idea in case you have some space-separated skills like `Short Blade` (since it becomes `ShortBlade` and fails), so I've replaced it with `.strip()` string method instead.

Comment: Completely forgot about skills that have spaces, thank you.